# More than one image on UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, image, ipad, uitableview

I need to put two images into a iOS tableview.

I used this code to place the image in a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"verde_diversos.png"];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
cell.textLabel.text = [self.colorNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]; 

return cell;
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create your own `UITableViewCell` subclass. In its initialiser you would set up two `UIImageView`s and add them to the `contentView` as subviews of it. Then in `layoutSubviews` you would set the frames of the `UIImageView`s based on how you want them laid out.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

UIImageView *cellView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)] autorelease];
cellView.tag = 555;

[cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];
}

UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"verde_diversos.png"];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
cell.textLabel.text = [self.colorNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]; 

UIImageView *secondImage = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:555];
secondImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: if you add the UIImageView to `cell.contentView` I'll upvote you. Subviews of a cell should go into contentView so stretching/shrinking (e.g. when you add an accessoryView) of the cell works correctly